# WCF callback in WPF application

Tags: wpf, wcf

I wrote WCF server and silverlight application that using this WCF service method. 
Any WCF service method that i call from the silverlight - i get 'callback' from the server.

Now, i wrote small WPF desktop applicaiton - and i don't get any 'callback' when i calling the same WCF service method ( the WCF service and the WPF application does not run on same machine )

Is it OK ?

Is there any way to get 'callback' from WPF app. like in Silverlight ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use WCF with Silverlight, it automatically makes the WCF server calls Asynchronous and adds the callbacks.

WPF does not do this by default. To generate the Async operations, you  need to go into the ServivceReference Properties and check the `Generate asynchronous operations` box.

[image: ServiceReference Screenshot]